# How to declare and edit a multidimensional array?

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, ms-word

How do I declare a multidimensional array in Word VBA? And does it have to be a fixed size, or can I add additional values later on?

Most of the sources I'm finding for arrays are for VB.NET, not for VBA, but I'm working on a Word macros.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html ?

Comment: Googled: "vba declare multidimensional array" [First result](https://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html).  The keyword you'll want to search for to re-dimension is redim.

Comment: Is the syntax for Excel VBA and Word VBA the same?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is the same for VBA running in *all* applications since this is a basic functionality of the VBA language, rather than something specific to the application hosting it. So the same thing will also work in PowerPoint, Access, Project, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dim [**yourVariable**]([**array**], [**array**]......) As[**DataType**]

Example:

### 2D Array:

```
Option Explicit

Dim SampleArray(0 To 10, 0 To 10) As String

Private Sub Sample()

    SampleArray(0, 0) = "0, 0"
    SampleArray(1, 0) = "1, 0"
    SampleArray(0, 2) = "0, 2"
    SampleArray(0, 3) = "0, 3"
    SampleArray(2, 4) = "2, 4"

    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(1, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 2)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 3)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(2, 4)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Sample
End Sub
```

### 3D array:

```
Option Explicit

Dim SampleArray(0 To 10, 0 To 10, 0 To 10) As String

Private Sub Sample()

    SampleArray(0, 0, 0) = "0, 0, 0"
    SampleArray(1, 0, 0) = "1, 0, 0"
    SampleArray(0, 2, 0) = "0, 2, 0"
    SampleArray(0, 3, 0) = "0, 3, 0"
    SampleArray(2, 4, 0) = "2, 4, 0"

    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(1, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 2, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(0, 3, 0)
    Debug.Print SampleArray(2, 4, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Sample
End Sub
```